# Advanced Problems with file/folder permissions on Windows 7 - ownership?

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions, file-sharing

I messed up with some folder's right click>Proprieties>Security Tab. Those folders are in an external HDD. The outcome of such a thing like (like messing with stuff you don't fully understand) is that now, when the HDD is connected to another PC, those same folders become accessible only after providing the administrator password (a pop up message saying: "you don't currently have permission to access this folder" is shown for the folders and their sub-folders and their respective contents).

Is there a way to restore those folders to their normal state where they can be accessed/watched by anyone with out any permissions whatsoever (and the files inside them too of course), like any normal windows folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the owner and permissions to "Everyone". You might have to go into the properties twice: first for ownership, then second for permissions.

- Right-click > `Properties` > `Security` (tab)
- Click `Advanced` > `Owner` (tab) > `Edit`
- Click `Other users or groups` > type `Everyone` > click `OK`
- Check `Replace owner on subcontainers and objects` (make sure `Everyone` is selected)
- Click `OK`

You should be back at the `Advanced Security Settings for Folder` window. Only do this next step if the folder doesn't show "Everyone" in the list.

- Click `Permissions` (tab) > `Change Permissions`
- Remove all entries in the list
- Click `Add` and add `Everyone` like before
- Click on the `Allow` checkbox next to `Full control` and it will populate everything for you
- Check the `Apply these permissions to objects and / or containers within this container only`
- Click `OK`
- Click `OK`
- Click `OK`
- Click `OK`

Comment: Ok...but how do i accomplish that?. Sure, right click>Properties>Security... and after that i'm lost (sure i could guess, but doing that is what got me here in the first place...)

Comment: I've edited my answer to tell you how to do this.